# Border-top not inline, border-bottom inline

Tags: html, css, border

I have a simple image which I want to give a border-top and border bottom. This is my code:

```
<div class="details-big">
    <img src="../images/full/full21.jpg" alt="title" />
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.details-big {
    border-top: 8px solid #f0f0f0;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #f0f0f0;
}
```

The problem is that the border-top cuts off a part of the image, while the border-bottom does the opposite, and adds white padding even before the border-bottom is displayed.

I would simply like the borders to be added neatly to the border without any spaces or parts of the image being cut off. Is this possible with CSS?

Comment: Just apply the border to the img element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it's not cut off at the top, it just has a space at the bottom, which is rendered by the inline `img`. If your div contains only the image, you can just set `font-size:0` for your div. Also you can set the border for your `img` instead:

```
.details-big {
  border-top: 8px solid #f0f0f0;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #f0f0f0;    
  font-size:0;
}
```

You can also set `display:block` for your `img`:

```
.details-big > img {
  display:block;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/FNTqq/)

Comment: Would have never thought of that but they both work perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @2339870 you're welcome, in fact we have more tricks to fight against the strange whitespace caused by inline elements, you can find more here http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ . However looks like there are some tricks which can't be applied on the `<img>` in this case.